# Как подключить longpool к странице ВК?

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, long-poll

Код:

```
import vk_api
import requests
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType

session = requests.Session()
vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token='токен')
vk = vk_session.get_api()
longpool = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session)
vk.messages.send(random_id=0,user_id=айди,message="OK")
```

Это токен от страницы, но вот как подключить longpool если он требует айди группы?

Comment: А как Вы получили токен от страницы?

Comment: Отправляю сообщения с помощью токена для VkAdmin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

замените

```
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType
```

на

```
from vk_api.longpoll import VkLongPoll, VkEventType
```

а

```
longpool = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session)
```

на

```
longpoll = VkLongPoll(vk_session)
```

и можете спокойно писать

```
while True:
    for event in longpoll.listen():
```